# Component and Profller tabs no longer show in React

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I installed the React Developer tools a while ago and they worked fine. But now the Components and Profiler Tabs no longer show up when I bring up the tools. I've uninstalled them and reinstalled several times and still no luck. When I click on the React Icon it tells me this as it always has:

This page is using the production build of React. ✅
Open the developer tools, and "Components" and "Profiler" tabs will appear to the right.

But when I open developer tools these tabs are no longer there as they used to be.

Any ideas what's up?

Comment: Sounds like https://crbug.com/1093731. Try moving the extension panels to the beginning. Or use Chrome Canary where the bug should be fixed.